# Use SVG in Static Resource with LWC:Map

Tags: svg, lightning-map

I am implementing the LWC Map component as defined [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-map/documentation).

I want to implement a SVG Icon on the map, and I can successfully do that by defining a path definition but I'd like to store the ICON as a Static Resource vs coding in the path definition as described in the docs. I am able to import the SVG from a SR per docs, and display it as an SVG in the Component, so I know that works, but it's not clear if I can do what I want re setting the Marker Icon to use my Static Resource. I tried some things like:

```
import SRIMPORT from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/SRIMPORTSVG';

mycustomicon = `${SRIMPORT}#myicon`;

mapIcon = this.mycustomicon;
```

But no joy. Anyone managed to do this? Or do I have to just use the path definition in the code?

Answer (score 1):

Imports are just resource paths (URI). To get the contents, you can fetch it:

```
let result = await fetch(SRIIMPORT);
let content = await result.text();
// `content` now contains the SVG markup from the static resource
```

However, this is still going to be raw XML, whereas `mapIcon` wants a formatted object, so you'll have to process the SVG into a suitable form. You can use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) directly, or utilize a library to help parse the data.